# adduser tells me group already exists!

Tags: 18.04, users

I am trying to add a user to my Ubuntu Server (`18.04 LTS`). When I run the command:

`adduser phoneden`

I get the message:

> adduser: The group `phoneden' already exists.

Which is true, as a group, phoneden does exist, because before the above, I ran `addgroup phoneden`.

But that doesn't explain why I can't add `phoneden` as a user too?

Comment: Do you want `phoneden` to be the new user's primary group or one of their supplementary groups? Did you try `adduser --ingroup phoneden`?

Comment: If the problem is why a user has a group with their name, [this](https://security.ias.edu/how-and-why-user-private-groups-unix) may be of use

Comment: @steeldriver basically I want it to be `phoneden : phoneden`. The user and group to be both `phoneden` and that user should not be in any other groups.

Comment: @steeldriver when I ran the command you suggested I got `adduser: Only one or two names allowed.`

Comment: sorry that probably should have been `adduser --ingroup phoneden phoneden`